# IntelliJ Perl Camelcade - Comment at first column

Tags: perl, intellij-idea

I'd like to change the behaviour of the `Comment with line comment` function. I'm using the Perl (Camelcade) Plugin.

When I comment with line comment the `#` will be added at the first column of the line. Is there any chance to set this on the first character?

**Example:**

```
sub test {
    my $log           = $self->{__logger};
    my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
```

**is actual becoming:**

```
sub test {
    my $log            = $self->{__logger};
#    my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
```

**My preference would be:**

```
sub test {
    my $log            = $self->{__logger};
    # my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
```

Is there way to change this behaviour?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4301.25, built on January 15, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b11 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.4
+ Perl Camelcade Plugin
```

---

**Addition:**

We use Perl::Tidy and Perl::Tidy will do:

```
sub test {
    if ( something ) {
        my $log           = $self->{__logger};
#        my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
    }
    ...
```

-->

```
sub test {
    if ( something ) {
        my $log           = $self->{__logger};
        #        my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
    }
    ...
```

That is the reasion why I'd like to change this behaviour. E.g.: Visual Studio Code and other editors do:

```
sub test {
    if ( something ) {
        my $log           = $self->{__logger};
        # my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
    }
    ...
```

-->

```
sub test {
    if ( something ) {
        my $log           = $self->{__logger};
        # my $sRegexPattern = $self->getMetaFields;
    }
    ...
```

so Perl::Tidy won't ruin the look.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reformat Code"?

Comment: I'm using `Re-Format with Perl::Tidy` instead of `Reformat Code` because we have defined standards. That's the reasion why I'd like to change the behaviour of `Comment with line comment` because Perl::Tidy will move the line to the current block if the `#` is on the first column instead before the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue 1767](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/issues/1767) on github.

> Cooming in Milestone [2018.1.2](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/milestone/22)